# C# - Selenium: StaleElementReferenceException on any element on any webpage after refresh or page change

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I'm getting a StaleElementReferenceException (Element is not attached to the page document) whenever I try to use Actions to move to an element not on the page the driver is first loaded with; however, the element shows up in both the DOM and the page source. I'm using Selenium with ChromeDriver version 2.30. I've tried running Chome in headless mode as well. I've also tried to switch the binary to Chrome beta and Chrome Canary.

```
        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30));
        wait.Until(d =>
        {
            try
            {
                IWebElement e = driver.FindElementById(ID);
                builder.MoveToElement(e).Build().Perform();
                builder.Click().Build().Perform();
                return true;
            }
            catch { }
            return false;
        });
```

It tries multiple times to find the element, but never can; it hangs on MoveToElement and returns the exception. As you can see, I've already tried to wrap the whole thing in a try/catch loop; it still never gets the element. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: you can try builder.Click(e).Build().Perform(); instead of builder.MoveToElement(e).Build().Perform();
                builder.Click().Build().Perform();

Comment: Does that still emulate mouse movement?

Comment: Can you paste the HTML code of the element as well as let us know if there are any javascripts loading that element ? The error occurs if you create a reference of an element and then before performing an action on it, page changes and element is not present anymore.

Comment: <div id="da1a" style="height:50px;font-size:12px;" class="f_r">

There is no javascript code running on the element. I don't believe that is the issue, however, as the error is thrown whenever the page is changed or refreshed from the original page that the driver loads on, even if it's the same exact page.

Comment: I get the same error with ChromeDriver 2.29 and 2.30.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a new `Actions` object. They're apparently page-specific, so the old one stops working after navigation.

```
builder = new Actions(driver);
```